# Gauge Groups in Nature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory

It is well known that the relevant gauge groups appearing in particle physics are $U(1)$, $SU(2)$, and $SU(3)$. In many respects these are among the simplest Lie groups, such as in the dimension of their Cartan subalgebras, the size of their irreducible representations, and the fact that $U(1)$ is abelian. Is there a reason why the simplest groups are the most relevant? I am aware of the fact that they were determined empirically, but I'm wondering if there is a deeper principle underlying the presence of these groups. For example, why do we not observe a universe based on something like $SU(835)$ with an obscenely large number of particles?

Comment: It's a good question. I don't think it is a duplicate. I'd also point out that larger groups have been considered in grand unified theory like SU(5) and SO(10) as well as E8.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the other question, because the basic question is "Why this particular choice of gauge group?" I think everyone would like to know the answer to that question! We can speculate based on hypothetical unified theories, but no one knows the answer.